# Invalid API Key provided in creating token (Stripe)

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

How to fix Invalid API Key provided: cus_****

```
card = stripe.Token.create(customer_id, method)
                    
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
   amount=price,
   currency='usd',
   description=desc,
   receipt_email=request.user.email,
   source=card
   )
```

I've tried adding the account id to Token.create like this:

```
            card = stripe.Token.create(stripe_account_id, customer_id, method)
```

but that gives the error Invalid API Key provided: acct_**** and I think that's what I'm supposed to be using so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

edit: Turns out I shouldn't have been trying to create a token at all.
I was trying to use a card saved to my customer and my code should have been just this with no Token.create():

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
   amount=price,
   currency='usd',
   description=desc,
   receipt_email=request.user.email,
   source=method, # references card_id
   customer= customer_id
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass a Customer id when creating a Token. Instead, use the example from the API reference:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card

Comment: Okay, tried creating with just the id but it gives a different error
Request req_***: Received unknown parameter: card[id]
using this line instead
                card = stripe.Token.create(card={"id": method})

Comment: Rather than looking at that method, reference the API (same link as above) and select the library you're using.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I couldn't figure out that I didn't need the token creation at all